# git filter-branch man page issue

Tags: git, version-control

## question

**man git-filter-branch** shows a great example of how to rewrite a GIT repo commit history in order to have all commits changed so that one might think that all commits were down in a subdirectory. basically one moves all files in the respective repository without loosing history.

this can be used to merge two different compatible repositories which both have files/directories with the same names.

**question: one can call this example in two different ways, why does the 1:1 paste from the manpage (1.) work but (2.) fails?**

all i did was to reformat the command so that it only requires one line.

## 1. calling the command (multiple lines)

```
       git filter-branch --index-filter \
               'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&newsubdir/-" |
                       GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
                               git update-index --index-info &&
                mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

Rewrite 3720c8434560995123b922597a45e16e57c0b0d9 (278/278)

Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten

## 2. calling the command (in one line)

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&toplevel/-" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE""' HEAD
```

Rewrite 51662df070793ac10b6c8c9bbdca5f6f7c7b74bd (1/278)/nix/store/wiw6axjcyds0zk1nxfxk50zqs6mmfyg9-git-1.8.5.2/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: eval: line 329: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/nix/store/wiw6axjcyds0zk1nxfxk50zqs6mmfyg9-git-1.8.5.2/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: eval: line 330: syntax error: unexpected end of file
index filter failed: git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&toplevel/-" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE""

Comment: I see two close-double-quotes before the final close-single-quote at the end of the one-line version.  That looks like it's the syntax error in question.

Comment: exactly! thanks so much... wasted far too much time with this so far.